# Malware changed all file extension and name in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, malware

Malware changed all file extension and name in mysql database. I have changed them back to the normal but in phpMyAdmin, they are show showing corrupted when i click on them it shows error 1033 Incorrect information in file .

Can anyone give me suggestion how can i solve the issue, Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know it didn't change the data in the files?    Safest bet one would think would be to wipe/reload from backup.

Comment: you are right, it have encrypted the data